# .load(fn) no funciona al migrar a .on('load') Jquery 3.1

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

Después de haber actualizado de **.load() a .on('load')**, da problemas, en chrome no se ejecuta el código al cargarse la primera vez, debo volver a refrescar la página varias veces. Lo mismo ocurre en Internet explorer.

**Migre de jquery 1.11 a la versión 3.1**

Alguna idea del por qué puede estar pasando esto ?

Comment: Cual es el código que utilizas? como cargas ese load?

Answer (score 0):

Vamos por partes:

[.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) Carga datos desde el server desde una URL específica y coloca el contenido resultado en un elemento definido.

[load event](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) Ocurre cuando un elemento y sus elementos hijos han cargado completamente, este evento aplica sólo a cierto tipo de elementos HTML.

Ahora bien, una advertencia sobre el uso de imágenes mediante load event `on('load', function(){...})`:

1. No trabaja de manera consistente  ni fiable en diversos navegadores.
2. No se ejecuta correctamente en WebKit(el motor que tiene Google Chrome) si el src de imagen está ajustado a la misma src como antes.
3. No hace correctamente la burbuja hasta el árbol DOM
4. Puede dejar de mostrar imágenes que ya viven en la caché del navegador.

Considerando la poca información mostrada en tu pregunta, siento que tiene que ver con el punto 2 y el punto 4.

Answer (score -1):

Lla única solución que le encontré fue usar la versión 2.4 de **Jquery** y no la 3.1